# TI TIVAC GPIO Port Write of an entire Byte at once

Tags: gpio

My project uses the TI TM4C129ENCPDTI3 MCU using Code Composer Studio version 9.0.1.00004 with TivaWare_C_Series-2.2.0.295, bios_6_83_00_18, and xdctools_3_32_00_06_core running on Windows 10 pro.

I am working on a project that requires me to write 8 bits at once a GPIO port as efficiently as possible. I have been looking and can't locate a direct port write or read capability; surely I am overlooking the obvious.  This is a basic capability of every IDE/MCU I have ever worked with.  I feel stupid for asking, but I am stumped.

Need to accomplish something along the lines of:

uint8_t outByte = 0x55;

GPIO_PORTA = outByte;  // I need a statement here that will write the 0x55 data to the port pins in parallel without having to resort to bitwise dissasembly of outByte and sending it one bit at a time.

Here is the code I have tried:

```
#include <ti/sysbios/BIOS.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "pinout.h"
#include "inc/hw_gpio.h"
#include "inc/hw_memmap.h"
#include "driverlib/sysctl.h"
#include "driverlib/rom_map.h"
#include "driverlib/gpio.h"
#include "driverlib/pin_map.h"
#include "driverlib/interrupt.h"
#include "Lan.h"
#include "UdpServer.h"
#include "RIB_IO.h"

/* XDC module Headers */
#include <xdc/std.h>
#include <xdc/runtime/Error.h>
#include <xdc/runtime/System.h>

/* BIOS module Headers */
#include <ti/sysbios/BIOS.h>
#include <ti/sysbios/knl/Clock.h>
#include <ti/sysbios/knl/Task.h>
#include <ti/sysbios/knl/Semaphore.h>

.
.
.

Int main()
{
   SysCtlMOSCConfigSet(SYSCTL_MOSC_HIGHFREQ);
        //
        // Set the clocking to run directly from the crystal at 120MHz.
        //
    g_SysClock = MAP_SysCtlClockFreqSet((SYSCTL_XTAL_25MHZ |
                                                 SYSCTL_OSC_MAIN |
                                                 SYSCTL_USE_PLL |
                                                 SYSCTL_CFG_VCO_480), 120000000);
    PinoutSet();


.
.
.

    // Write PORT Test Data (A,D,K,L)
    *(volatile unsigned long *)0x400043FC = 0x55;


}
```

PINOUT.C

```
    //*****************************************************************************
//
// Configure the device pins for different signals
//
// Copyright (C) 2014 Texas Instruments Incorporated - http://www.ti.com/ 
// 
// 
//  Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without 
//  modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions 
//  are met:
//
//    Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright 
//    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
//
//    Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
//    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the 
//    documentation and/or other materials provided with the   
//    distribution.
//
//    Neither the name of Texas Instruments Incorporated nor the names of
//    its contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
//    from this software without specific prior written permission.
//
//  THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS 
//  "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT 
//  LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
//  A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT 
//  OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, 
//  SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT 
//  LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE,
//  DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY
//  THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT 
//  (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE 
//  OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
//
//*****************************************************************************

// This file was automatically generated on 1/12/2021 at 4:57:49 PM
// by TI PinMux version 1.6.0+1543
//
//*****************************************************************************

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "inc/hw_gpio.h"
#include "inc/hw_memmap.h"
#include "inc/hw_types.h"
#include "driverlib/gpio.h"
#include "driverlib/pin_map.h"
#include "driverlib/rom.h"
#include "driverlib/rom_map.h"
#include "driverlib/sysctl.h"
#include "pinout.h"

//*****************************************************************************
//
//! \addtogroup pinout_api
//! @{
//
//*****************************************************************************

//*****************************************************************************
//
//! Configures the device pins for the customer specific usage.
//!
//! \return None.
//
//*****************************************************************************
void
PinoutSet(void)
{
    //
    // Enable Peripheral Clocks 
    //
    MAP_SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPIOA);
    MAP_SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPIOB);
    MAP_SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPIOD);
    MAP_SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPIOF);
    MAP_SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPIOG);
    MAP_SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPIOJ);
    MAP_SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPIOK);
    MAP_SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPIOL);
    MAP_SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPIOM);
    MAP_SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPION);
    MAP_SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPIOP);
    MAP_SysCtlPeripheralEnable(SYSCTL_PERIPH_GPIOQ);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PF0
    // for EN0LED0
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinConfigure(GPIO_PF0_EN0LED0);
    GPIOPinTypeEthernetLED(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_0);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PF4
    // for EN0LED1
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinConfigure(GPIO_PF4_EN0LED1);
    GPIOPinTypeEthernetLED(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_4);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PG0
    // for EN0PPS
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinConfigure(GPIO_PG0_EN0PPS);
    GPIOPinTypeEthernetMII(GPIO_PORTG_BASE, GPIO_PIN_0);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PF1
    // for EN0LED2
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinConfigure(GPIO_PF1_EN0LED2);
    GPIOPinTypeEthernetLED(GPIO_PORTF_BASE, GPIO_PIN_1);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PA0
    // for GPIO_PA0
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTA_BASE, GPIO_PIN_0);
    MAP_GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTA_BASE, GPIO_PIN_0, GPIO_PIN_0);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PA1
    // for GPIO_PA1
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTA_BASE, GPIO_PIN_1);
    MAP_GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTA_BASE, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_1);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PA2
    // for GPIO_PA2
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTA_BASE, GPIO_PIN_2);
    MAP_GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTA_BASE, GPIO_PIN_2, GPIO_PIN_2);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PA3
    // for GPIO_PA3
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTA_BASE, GPIO_PIN_3);
    MAP_GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTA_BASE, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_3);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PA4
    // for GPIO_PA4
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTA_BASE, GPIO_PIN_4);
    MAP_GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTA_BASE, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_4);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PA5
    // for GPIO_PA5
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTA_BASE, GPIO_PIN_5);
    MAP_GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTA_BASE, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_5);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PA6
    // for GPIO_PA6
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTA_BASE, GPIO_PIN_6);
    MAP_GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTA_BASE, GPIO_PIN_6, GPIO_PIN_6);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PA7
    // for GPIO_PA7
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTA_BASE, GPIO_PIN_7);
    MAP_GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTA_BASE, GPIO_PIN_7, GPIO_PIN_7);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PD0
    // for GPIO_PD0
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTD_BASE, GPIO_PIN_0);
    MAP_GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTD_BASE, GPIO_PIN_0, GPIO_PIN_0);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PD1
    // for GPIO_PD1
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTD_BASE, GPIO_PIN_1);
    MAP_GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTD_BASE, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_1);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PD2
    // for GPIO_PD2
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTD_BASE, GPIO_PIN_2);
    MAP_GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTD_BASE, GPIO_PIN_2, GPIO_PIN_2);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PD3
    // for GPIO_PD3
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTD_BASE, GPIO_PIN_3);
    MAP_GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTD_BASE, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_3);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PD4
    // for GPIO_PD4
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTD_BASE, GPIO_PIN_4);
    MAP_GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTD_BASE, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_4);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PD5
    // for GPIO_PD5
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTD_BASE, GPIO_PIN_5);
    MAP_GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTD_BASE, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_5);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PD6
    // for GPIO_PD6
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTD_BASE, GPIO_PIN_6);
    MAP_GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTD_BASE, GPIO_PIN_6, GPIO_PIN_6);

    //
    // Unlock the Port Pin and Set the Commit Bit
    //
    HWREG(GPIO_PORTD_BASE+GPIO_O_LOCK) = GPIO_LOCK_KEY;
    HWREG(GPIO_PORTD_BASE+GPIO_O_CR)   |= GPIO_PIN_7;
    HWREG(GPIO_PORTD_BASE+GPIO_O_LOCK) = 0x0;
    
    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PD7
    // for GPIO_PD7
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTD_BASE, GPIO_PIN_7);
    MAP_GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTD_BASE, GPIO_PIN_7, GPIO_PIN_7);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PK0
    // for GPIO_PK0
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTK_BASE, GPIO_PIN_0);
    MAP_GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTK_BASE, GPIO_PIN_0, GPIO_PIN_0);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PK1
    // for GPIO_PK1
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTK_BASE, GPIO_PIN_1);
    MAP_GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTK_BASE, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_1);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PK2
    // for GPIO_PK2
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTK_BASE, GPIO_PIN_2);
    MAP_GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTK_BASE, GPIO_PIN_2, GPIO_PIN_2);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PK3
    // for GPIO_PK3
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTK_BASE, GPIO_PIN_3);
    MAP_GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTK_BASE, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_3);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PK4
    // for GPIO_PK4
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTK_BASE, GPIO_PIN_4);
    MAP_GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTK_BASE, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_4);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PK5
    // for GPIO_PK5
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTK_BASE, GPIO_PIN_5);
    MAP_GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTK_BASE, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_5);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PK6
    // for GPIO_PK6
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTK_BASE, GPIO_PIN_6);
    MAP_GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTK_BASE, GPIO_PIN_6, GPIO_PIN_6);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PK7
    // for GPIO_PK7
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTK_BASE, GPIO_PIN_7);
    MAP_GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTK_BASE, GPIO_PIN_7, GPIO_PIN_7);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PL0
    // for GPIO_PL0
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTL_BASE, GPIO_PIN_0);
    MAP_GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTL_BASE, GPIO_PIN_0, GPIO_PIN_0);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PL1
    // for GPIO_PL1
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTL_BASE, GPIO_PIN_1);
    MAP_GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTL_BASE, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_1);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PL2
    // for GPIO_PL2
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTL_BASE, GPIO_PIN_2);
    MAP_GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTL_BASE, GPIO_PIN_2, GPIO_PIN_2);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PL3
    // for GPIO_PL3
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTL_BASE, GPIO_PIN_3);
    MAP_GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTL_BASE, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_3);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PL4
    // for GPIO_PL4
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTL_BASE, GPIO_PIN_4);
    MAP_GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTL_BASE, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_4);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PL5
    // for GPIO_PL5
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTL_BASE, GPIO_PIN_5);
    MAP_GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTL_BASE, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_PIN_5);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PL6
    // for GPIO_PL6
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTL_BASE, GPIO_PIN_6);
    MAP_GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTL_BASE, GPIO_PIN_6, GPIO_PIN_6);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PL7
    // for GPIO_PL7
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTL_BASE, GPIO_PIN_7);
    MAP_GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTL_BASE, GPIO_PIN_7, GPIO_PIN_7);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PM0
    // for GPIO_PM0
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOInput(GPIO_PORTM_BASE, GPIO_PIN_0);
    MAP_GPIOPadConfigSet(GPIO_PORTM_BASE, GPIO_PIN_0, GPIO_STRENGTH_2MA, GPIO_PIN_TYPE_STD_WPU);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PM1
    // for GPIO_PM1
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOInput(GPIO_PORTM_BASE, GPIO_PIN_1);
    MAP_GPIOPadConfigSet(GPIO_PORTM_BASE, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_STRENGTH_2MA, GPIO_PIN_TYPE_STD_WPU);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PM2
    // for GPIO_PM2
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOInput(GPIO_PORTM_BASE, GPIO_PIN_2);
    MAP_GPIOPadConfigSet(GPIO_PORTM_BASE, GPIO_PIN_2, GPIO_STRENGTH_2MA, GPIO_PIN_TYPE_STD_WPU);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PM3
    // for GPIO_PM3
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOInput(GPIO_PORTM_BASE, GPIO_PIN_3);
    MAP_GPIOPadConfigSet(GPIO_PORTM_BASE, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_STRENGTH_2MA, GPIO_PIN_TYPE_STD_WPU);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PM4
    // for GPIO_PM4
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOInput(GPIO_PORTM_BASE, GPIO_PIN_4);
    MAP_GPIOPadConfigSet(GPIO_PORTM_BASE, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_STRENGTH_2MA, GPIO_PIN_TYPE_STD_WPU);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PM5
    // for GPIO_PM5
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOInput(GPIO_PORTM_BASE, GPIO_PIN_5);
    MAP_GPIOPadConfigSet(GPIO_PORTM_BASE, GPIO_PIN_5, GPIO_STRENGTH_2MA, GPIO_PIN_TYPE_STD_WPU);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PM6
    // for GPIO_PM6
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOInput(GPIO_PORTM_BASE, GPIO_PIN_6);
    MAP_GPIOPadConfigSet(GPIO_PORTM_BASE, GPIO_PIN_6, GPIO_STRENGTH_2MA, GPIO_PIN_TYPE_STD_WPU);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PM7
    // for GPIO_PM7
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOInput(GPIO_PORTM_BASE, GPIO_PIN_7);
    MAP_GPIOPadConfigSet(GPIO_PORTM_BASE, GPIO_PIN_7, GPIO_STRENGTH_2MA, GPIO_PIN_TYPE_STD_WPU);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PQ4
    // for GPIO_PQ4
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOInput(GPIO_PORTQ_BASE, GPIO_PIN_4);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PQ3
    // for GPIO_PQ3
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOInput(GPIO_PORTQ_BASE, GPIO_PIN_3);
    MAP_GPIOPadConfigSet(GPIO_PORTQ_BASE, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_STRENGTH_2MA, GPIO_PIN_TYPE_STD_WPU);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PQ2
    // for GPIO_PQ2
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOInput(GPIO_PORTQ_BASE, GPIO_PIN_2);
    MAP_GPIOPadConfigSet(GPIO_PORTQ_BASE, GPIO_PIN_2, GPIO_STRENGTH_2MA, GPIO_PIN_TYPE_STD_WPU);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PQ1
    // for GPIO_PQ1
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOInput(GPIO_PORTQ_BASE, GPIO_PIN_1);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PQ0
    // for GPIO_PQ0
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOInput(GPIO_PORTQ_BASE, GPIO_PIN_0);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PN5
    // for GPIO_PN5
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTN_BASE, GPIO_PIN_5);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PN4
    // for GPIO_PN4
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTN_BASE, GPIO_PIN_4);
    MAP_GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTN_BASE, GPIO_PIN_4, GPIO_PIN_4);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PN3
    // for GPIO_PN3
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTN_BASE, GPIO_PIN_3);
    MAP_GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTN_BASE, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_3);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PN2
    // for GPIO_PN2
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTN_BASE, GPIO_PIN_2);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PN1
    // for GPIO_PN1
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTN_BASE, GPIO_PIN_1);
    MAP_GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTN_BASE, GPIO_PIN_1, GPIO_PIN_1);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PN0
    // for GPIO_PN0
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeGPIOOutput(GPIO_PORTN_BASE, GPIO_PIN_0);
    MAP_GPIOPinWrite(GPIO_PORTN_BASE, GPIO_PIN_0, 0x0);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PB2
    // for I2C0SCL
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinConfigure(GPIO_PB2_I2C0SCL);
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeI2CSCL(GPIO_PORTB_BASE, GPIO_PIN_2);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PB3
    // for I2C0SDA
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinConfigure(GPIO_PB3_I2C0SDA);
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeI2C(GPIO_PORTB_BASE, GPIO_PIN_3);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PJ0
    // for U3RX
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinConfigure(GPIO_PJ0_U3RX);
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeUART(GPIO_PORTJ_BASE, GPIO_PIN_0);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PJ1
    // for U3TX
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinConfigure(GPIO_PJ1_U3TX);
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeUART(GPIO_PORTJ_BASE, GPIO_PIN_1);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PP5
    // for U3CTS
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinConfigure(GPIO_PP5_U3CTS);
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeUART(GPIO_PORTP_BASE, GPIO_PIN_5);

    //
    // Configure the GPIO Pin Mux for PP4
    // for U3RTS
    //
    MAP_GPIOPinConfigure(GPIO_PP4_U3RTS);
    MAP_GPIOPinTypeUART(GPIO_PORTP_BASE, GPIO_PIN_4);

}

//*****************************************************************************
//
// Close the Doxygen group.
//! @}
//
//*****************************************************************************
```

PINOUT.H

```
//*****************************************************************************
// pinout.h
//
// configure the device pins for different signals
//
// Copyright (C) 2014 Texas Instruments Incorporated - http://www.ti.com/ 
// 
// 
//  Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without 
//  modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions 
//  are met:
//
//    Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright 
//    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
//
//    Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
//    notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the 
//    documentation and/or other materials provided with the   
//    distribution.
//
//    Neither the name of Texas Instruments Incorporated nor the names of
//    its contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
//    from this software without specific prior written permission.
//
//  THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS 
//  "AS IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT 
//  LIMITED TO, THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR
//  A PARTICULAR PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT 
//  OWNER OR CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, 
//  SPECIAL, EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT 
//  LIMITED TO, PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE,
//  DATA, OR PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY
//  THEORY OF LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT 
//  (INCLUDING NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE 
//  OF THIS SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
//
//*****************************************************************************

// This file was automatically generated on 1/12/2021 at 4:57:49 PM
// by TI PinMux version 1.6.0+1543
//
//*****************************************************************************

#ifndef __DRIVERS_PINOUT_H__
#define __DRIVERS_PINOUT_H__

//*****************************************************************************
//
// If building with a C++ compiler, make all of the definitions in this header
// have a C binding.
//
//*****************************************************************************
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

//*****************************************************************************
//
// Prototypes.
//
//*****************************************************************************
extern void PinoutSet(void);

//*****************************************************************************
//
// Mark the end of the C bindings section for C++ compilers.
//
//*****************************************************************************
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif // __DRIVERS_PINOUT_H__
```

Comment: Good question, but you may get a better response at: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Answered by TI e2e forum.  Turns out that the GPIOPinWrite function uses a pin mask to determine which pins to write.  If the mask is set to all pins then the data written will change all 8 pin states.

One can also bypass TivaWare and use direct port access via a HWREG MACRO which seems to execute faster.

```
#include "driverlib/gpio.h"
#include "inc/hw_gpio.h"
#include "inc/hw_ints.h"
#include "inc/hw_memmap.h"
#include "inc/hw_types.h"

uint32_t PortA = GPIO_PORTA_BASE + (GPIO_O_DATA + (0xFF << 2));

uint32_t DebugPin = GPIO_PORTQ_BASE + (GPIO_O_DATA + (GPIO_PIN_4 << 2));

    //toggle debug pin
    HWREG(DebugPin) = GPIO_PIN_4;
```